# How can I find the credit card balance regarding my code?

Tags: python

```
def balance (p, apr, mo):
mpr = 0.01*apr/12
for month in range(int(mo)):
    p= p+p*mpr
    return p
```

I'm a beginner trying to create a function that will return the balance on a credit card starting balance p and interest rate apr after mo months. When I run my code, it seems like the loop will not work.

Comment: You should unindent the return statement from the for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 def balance (p, apr, mo):
    mpr = 0.01*apr/12.0
    for month in range(int(mo)):
        p= p+p*mpr
    return p


for i in range(1,13):
    print balance(1000,10,i)
```

Strictly this mpr is not correct (monthly compounding is a simplification that was justified in times before slide rules); the monthly rate should be the 12th root of the annual rate; see  continous compounding https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest

```
def balance2 (p, apr, mo):
    mpr =  ((1+apr/100.0)**(1/12.0)-1)
    for month in range(int(mo)):
        p= p+p*mpr
    return p

print 
for i in range(1,13):
    print balance2(1000,10,i)
```

output:

```
1008.33333333
1016.73611111
1025.20891204
1033.75231964
1042.3669223
1051.05331332
1059.81209093
1068.64385836
1077.54922384
1086.52880071
1095.58320738
1104.71306744

1007.97414043
1016.01186777
1024.11368908
1032.28011546
1040.51166206
1048.80884817
1057.17219721
1065.60223677
1074.09949864
1082.66451888
1091.29783779
1100.0
```

Comment: Why are you importing numpy?

Comment: Thank you, my first version used  a log to take the 12th root. Numpy removed.